# How to read a .env file on MongooseModule in Nestjs?

Tags: mongoose, environment-variables, nestjs, config

So I am trying to add a config to my NestJs project, so far I've been using MongooseModule in order to connect to the Database but I was providing the full URL in MongooseModule.forRoot().

It was something like this:

```
//app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModuele } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://.....')]
})
```

So then I added the nestjs config and its looking like this:

```
//app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModuele } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
     imports: [ConfigModule],
     useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
      uri: config.get<string>('DB_HOST'),
     }),
     inject: [ConfigService],
   }),
  ]
})
```

But then got this error:

[Nest] 14098  - 06/01/2022, 7:16:42 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"

I also tried this way:

```
//app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModuele } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
     imports: [ConfigModule],
     useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
      uri: config.get<string>('DB_HOST'),
     }),
     inject: [ConfigService],
   }),
  ]
})
```

nest print this error:

ERROR [ExceptionHandler] The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

My .env file looks like this:

```
DB_HOST="mongodb://....."
```

It seems like that on the app.module MongooseModule is not reading my .env file, does anyone knows how to solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please try the following code, it works for me.

```
// app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  import: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: config.get<string>('MONGODB_URI'), // Loaded from .ENV
      })
    })
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include also `ConfigModule.forRoot()`, otherwise doesnt work

Comment: The line just under @Module({ should read 'imports:' not 'import:', otherwise there is an error.

Answer (score 3):

Here is complete working code. `connectionName` is used incase you have multiple databases in your app.

```
    @Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    CostingModule,
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      connectionName: 'finance',
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: config.get<string>('MONGODB_URI_FINANCEDB'),
      }),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need any configuration file.
You can just write **process.env.DATABASE_URL** in app.module.ts file and set that env parameter from **cmd** like this:

```
set DATABASE_URL='url of your database'
```

and you can run your code